# How to center widgets on scene QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, python-3.x, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene, pyside2

I want to align the scene in the middle. My problem is that when you open an application, widgets are aligned somehow below the middle, but after hovering over buttons or a label, the widgets are aligned in the middle. Can I fix this somehow? Is there any right way to align the scene in the middle of the view?

Here is the whole code of my application:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(QSize(1080, 720))
        self.setWindowTitle('Graphics Scene')
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.mainview = QGraphicsView(self.centralwidget)
        self.mainview.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 1080, 720))

        alignment = Qt.Alignment(Qt.AlignVCenter, Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.mainview.setAlignment(alignment)

        # Main Scene (1)
        self.mainScene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.mainview.setScene(self.mainScene)

        self.labelTitle = QLabel('Main Scene')
        self.labelTitle.setStyleSheet('''
            QLabel {
                font: 48px 'Calibri';
                color: #999;
            }
        ''')

        styleForButtons = ('''
            QPushButton {
                margin: 0 70px;
                padding: 5px 30px;
            }
        ''')

        sizePolicy = QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.buttonPlay = QPushButton('Play')
        self.buttonSettings = QPushButton('Settings')
        self.buttonCredits = QPushButton('Credits')
        self.buttonMainExit = QPushButton('Exit')

        self.buttonPlay.setStyleSheet(styleForButtons)
        self.buttonSettings.setStyleSheet(styleForButtons)
        self.buttonCredits.setStyleSheet(styleForButtons)
        self.buttonMainExit.setStyleSheet(styleForButtons)

        self.buttonPlay.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.buttonSettings.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.buttonCredits.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.buttonMainExit.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

        self.itemLabelTitle = self.mainScene.addWidget(self.labelTitle)
        self.itemButtonPlay = self.mainScene.addWidget(self.buttonPlay)
        self.itemButtonSettings = self.mainScene.addWidget(self.buttonSettings)
        self.itemButtonCredits = self.mainScene.addWidget(self.buttonCredits)
        self.itemButtonMainExit = self.mainScene.addWidget(self.buttonMainExit)

        self.mainMenuLayout = QGraphicsGridLayout()

        self.mainMenuLayout.addItem(self.itemLabelTitle, 0, 0, alignment)
        self.mainMenuLayout.addItem(self.itemButtonPlay, 1, 0)
        self.mainMenuLayout.addItem(self.itemButtonSettings, 2, 0)
        self.mainMenuLayout.addItem(self.itemButtonCredits, 3, 0)
        self.mainMenuLayout.addItem(self.itemButtonMainExit, 4, 0)

        self.mainMenuWidget = QGraphicsWidget()
        self.mainMenuWidget.setLayout(self.mainMenuLayout)
        self.mainScene.addItem(self.mainMenuWidget)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**UPD: uploaded screenshots of what i see**

[image]

**I want to understand why my application behaves so strangely: firstly, why the widgets are not aligned exactly in the center, secondly, why there is a shift**

Comment: @eyllanesc, I thought, if you run this code on your computer, the application will behave in the same way as me: the widgets move upward after any actions (hover, keystroke)

Comment: What version of pyside2 do you have?

Comment: @eyllanesc, 1920x1080

Comment: @eyllanesc pyside2 5.11.2

Comment: @eyllanesc,PySide2.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 0.000000, 241.000000, 59.000000)
PySide2.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 0.000000, 259.000000, 201.000000)

Comment: try add `self.mainScene.setSceneRect(QRectF(QPointF(), self.mainMenuWidget.sizeHint(Qt.PreferredSize)))` before `self.mainScene.addItem(self.mainMenuWidget)`

Comment: @eyllanesc, yeah, it is worked. PySide2.QtCore.QRectF(0.000000, 0.000000, 259.000000, 201.000000). Aaaand, why it so? Why it is worked?

Comment: I will post an answer indicating the reasons.

Comment: I already published an answer explaining the reason for the problem, which is usually caused by the fact that a sceneRect was not established, so Qt internally tries to calculate an adequate one but fails to generate that unexpected behavior, so the solution is to establish it using the preferred size of the the widgets.

Comment: @eyllanesc, I understood, thank very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused because the scene does not have a `sceneRect()` set so when the `QGraphicsView` is displayed it sets the size of the scene using the resolution of the screen as a basis so it can initially have a size to the `boundingRect()` of all the items so that is centered with respect to that size and not with respect to the part of the scene that is shown in the `viewport()`, just after passing over the scene with the mouse the `update()` method is called and it updates to the correct size. So one solution is to set the `sceneRect()` using the size of the widget in scene coordinates.

```
self.mainScene.setSceneRect(QRectF(QPointF(), self.mainMenuWidget.sizeHint(Qt.PreferredSize))) 
self.mainScene.addItem(self.mainMenuWidget)
```